What are the approximate physical properties of a 1 in 10,000, unusually small adult human be?
Question context: Imagine we're selecting very small people for long distance space travel.  They require less space, less life support, less food... they have non-trivial advantages.
But the question is, how big is that? How much would they weigh?  How much less strong would they be? Is there a physical reason this might be a bad plan?
Obviously, medical conditions that lead to unusual sizes (dwarfism, pituitary gland issues, etc) would be excluded.
The mission in question would be an extended, remote task benefited by having more people.  Most likely, building initial Mars base.  Most of the work would be done by machines - so more controllers makes the task easier and faster.
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190027563/downloads/20190027563.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi0tYvFpuuIAxWI0wIHHW3uO1QQFnoECBcQBg&usg=AOvVaw31SRHQ3PbjAb02oObbPKap
This document states that kilos of life support supplies can be saved by using smaller people.  While some supplies (water, air) can be(eventually) provided locally the food requirements are much harder in the short term - and could represent a strong mass saving.
If... if we could nail down what our small staff look like.

The average adult human male is about 171 cm (5' 6") tall, but this average varies noticeably from country to country, from 160 cm (5' 3") in Yemen to 181 cm (5' 11") in Denmark. The shortest African Pigmy populations have adult males only about 150 cm (4' 11") tall on the average. Dwarfism is usually taken to mean adult height of 147 cm (4' 10") or less. The point is that 1 in 10,000 would not get you all that very far from the mean; the human species is pretty uniform.

Doesn't seem to be a worldbuilding problem to solve, just a straight demographics-data question. We have an [opendata.se] site that might interest you.

This seems like "the other side of the coin" to this question. Assuming that the humans can be short/small enough to make a material difference (I'm not convinced...) then this question suffers for not knowing anything about the mission. If all they need (like most crewed space missions) is to do things inside the ship at zero-G then all that really matters is that the ship can be designed to account for their lack of reach when strapped into their seats. Other than that, what's the specific mission?

Please confirm that "long distance space travel" does not mean generation ships, as a specific example of @JBH query about what the specific mission is.

Keep in mind that unless millimeters matter for some contrived reason, the way normal distributions work means that all you're really getting for limiting your selection pool to 1/10000 is a 200x smaller selection of people with the same size as the 1/50 selection pool.

According to a report I have (and will add to question later), the difference between a 5% and 95th percentile person, for daily consumables, are 3.9kg Vs 7.3 kg.

Mission update:  Go to Mars, 2-4 year mission, to set up and build initial infrastructure to produce resources locally.  At this stage, being able to support twice the on site staff, or more, with the same amount of food/life support could be magical.  365x3kgx4 (comment above) gives ~4.4T of saving.  Per person.

In general, if we're talking healthy (as in non-sick) humans, the height - or more simply - overall size is much less genetic than environmental. Of course there are Pygmes and there are also Maasai, but average human height, given same conditions from birth, should be about same across all races, ethnicities, etc. In other words: how tall what constitution an individual will have is most impacted by nutrition in first 2 years of life. That's why average human height varies most between eras, but not so much between ethnicities.

Looking at this growth chart and doing some shameless extrapolation, I got the mean height and standard deviation for US women at the age of twenty as 163.3 cm and 6.45 cm, respectively. From these we can calculate the height of a 0.01th percentile female as <139 cm.
Doing the same for men, the mean is 176.9 cm and standard deviation 7.25 cm. The 0.01th percentile male is <149 cm.
This is of course just a very rough approximation. It is assuming that human height follows the Gaussian distribution, and ignoring the fact that shortness can be caused by medical factors which would disqualify someone, as per your question. Finally, the data is from the US and does not represent wordwide averages. I hope the answer is still better than nothing.
I won't even try to estimate the weight of 0.01th percentile people, since from the same charts it's clear the distribution is not even close to Gaussian.

Use the Underground Astronauts as a baseline, they were all slim and around 5 foot 2 inches. But their relative strength was very good. Size is not a limiter on relative strength.
Relative strength is a lot more important than absolute strength in most activities except competitive power lifting, which wouldn't be necessary much in space I would think.
Small but strong people were necessary for their job which involved caving in very confined conditions.

If I could find a weight for some of them, this might well be a good compromise answer.  Small enough to be worth the optimisation, smart enough to do it (Masters+) and physically capable (rock climbing!).

@user2702772 around 50kg would be prime BMI for that height. I'd suggest 5ft2 males at 50kg & 5ft females at 45kg so you have some sexual dimorphism and strong agile people. This would be prime BMI humans.  You could go a couple or more inches smaller if you wanted and still have normal humans. Just use a BMI calculator to get a good weight for them.

The main issue you would be facing is that your major concern when choosing astronauts and future Mars colonists is not their size, but their skills, intelligence, education, personality and health necessary for a person to do their job and survive in space.
All those qualities already limit your choices to something like 1 in 10 MILLION already. You cannot just pick a random very small person and turn them into an astronaut by force, you need to pick the shortest, smallest person out of existing "space worthy" humans.
In humans, the physical and mental traits necessary for a person to be an astronaut tend to correlate with healthy upbringing, good, balanced diet, healthy genetics and Developed world ancestry, and these things in turn correlate with height.
Sure, there are very short and small statured people in Yemen, Burkina Faso, or Timor, but how many of them have the health, fitness, skills and knowledge needed in space?
Therefore, you are extremely unlikely to find someone who is both "astronaut material" and simultaneously very, very small.
In the end, you will have to pick your smallest astronauts out of a group of average-to-tall trainees, so it is unlikely your male astronauts would be shorter than 170cm, and female astronauts shorter than 150cm.
Trying to save fuel/money by sending small astronauts is not economically sensible. A person worth sending to space, let alone Mars, is already worth much more than the cost of sending their kilograms up.
If we make an alternative assumption that your colonists would be just passengers on the ship, and thus do not need to be skilled at all, and just need to be human and alive, then your best bet is to send a small cadre of astronauts with a batch of child prodigies, preferably ones that will grow into teenagers mid-trip.
